# How to do RewriteRule for different domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver, hostname

Good day,

I am referring to this article, https://niiconsulting.com/checkmate/2018/10/manipulating-host-headers-not-anymore/

In this article, there is some code as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,20}.){0,3}(domain1.com|domain2.com|domain3.com)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain1.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I have a web server that actually use by 3 application, with different port, and different domain name.

Base on the code on the website, if the host name does not meet any 3 of the domain, then it will redirect it to `domain1.com`.

I would like to ask, is it possible to make it like direct it back to own domain with 301 response?

Kindly advise.

Comment: Please note that this isn't related to Java at all so the Java tag is misleading here.

Comment: @Panadol What do you mean by "direct it back to own domain"?

Comment: As for the redirect: redirecting back to the own domain is possible. I'd have to look up the correct syntax but it should be something like `https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]`. The question, however, would be: why would you want to do that? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I have 3 web app, for example, https://uatmyappFinance.com, https://uatmyappGrocery.com and https://uatmyappStock.com, they are sharing the same web server, so I wish that if the user access to https://uatmyappFinance.com, and the hostname being change by attacker, then it should direct it back to https://uatmyappFinance.com, but base on my question, its look like it only can direct back to 1 domain.

Comment: @DusanBajic, I have 3 web app, for example, uatmyappFinance.com, uatmyappGrocery.com and uatmyappStock.com, they are sharing the same web server, so I wish that if the user access to uatmyappFinance.com, and the hostname being change by attacker, then it should direct it back to uatmyappFinance.com, but base on my question, its look like it only can direct back to 1 domain.

Comment: If I use numerical ip address (or some dummy hostname, that I pointed to your ip address), to which hostname do you want to redirect?

Comment: Well, attackers would change the hostname in the request already so your apache wouldn't even know that `uatmyappFinance.com` was meant to be the hostname  and thus how would you decide where to redirect the user (that also assumes the webserver would even react to the changed hostname)? If any attacker would be able to change the hostname in apache after the request has been received then you'd have a different problem already.